# How to build thrift to generate compiler for specific supported languages in centos 6.5

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, thrift, centos6.5

I have a fresh CentOS 6.5 instance which has yum updated and installed necessary development and other utilities. When I attempted to build apache thrift compiler in that setup doesn't build the compiler for other languages (python and cpp) specified in the configure script except java.

> [root@localDev thrift]# ./configure --with-java=yes
>   --with-python=yes --with-cpp=yes

And the output is as follows :

```
.
.
.
config.status: executing libtool commands

thrift 1.0.0-dev

Building C++ Library ......... : no
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : yes
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : no
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : no
Building Dart Library ........ : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : no
Building Lua Library ......... : no

Java Library:
   Using javac ............... : javac
   Using java ................ : java
   Using ant ................. : /usr/bin/ant

If something is missing that you think should be present,
please skim the output of configure to find the missing
component.  Details are present in config.log.
[root@localDev thrift]#
```

My dev setup has the following packages installed & updated :

open-jdk_1.7, python-2.7 and gcc compiler and its dependencies.

But miserably failed to build the compiler for python and cpp. Digged the config.log located under the same directory and not able to get the details. Helping hands are welcome.

Comment: Probably ... `# yum install gcc-c++ python-devel perl-devel lua-devel java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel`

Comment: Thanks @knud Larsen. I have already installed the necessary packages and its dependencies for thrift supported languages such as java, python and cpp.

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to build on Debian.

Comment: This helped me  http://blog.intelligencecomputing.io/middleware/869/install-thrift-on-linux